# Getting Cordova/Phonegap to emulate on Genymotion virtual device

Tags: node.js, cordova, android-emulator, npm, genymotion

Using the Cordova CLI, I set up an app and build it:

```
cordova create hi com.example.hi Hi 
cd hi
cordova platform add android
cordova build android
```

I run Genymotion and start a device named "api9". I run the Android Debug Bridge `adb devices`  and it shows as

```
192.168.8.101:5555
```

I try to launch the app with `cordova emulate android` but I get:

```
Error: An error occurred while emulating/deploying the android project. ...spawn ENOENT
```

However, launching the Android Virtual Device manager and starting an emulated device; the `cordova emulate android` works and `adb devices` lists;

```
192.168.8.101:5555
emulator-5554
```

What should I do to make Cordova emulate through Genymotion devices?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

It seems that `adb` sees genymotion virtual device as a real device and not as an emulated one, try `cordova run android` instead of `cordova emulate android`.

Comment: You made my day :) who would taught of that!

Comment: that's logical... in fact virtualbox based emulations acts as a real device.

Comment: At last a snappier way to emulate. Android SDK, with Nexus 7, is painfully sluggish on Mac OS X Yosemite, Imac 2008 12Gb RAM. Genymotion allows to test for more "real" top sellers devices, and a Galaxy S3 emulation is very reactive (using their librairies, not Android SDK - See Genymotion settings). Using the latest version of Genymotion as of 2015-02-01.

Answer (score 2):

When the device list is empty, which is not covered in this case, then you need to connect adb manually to the genymotion device.

Therefore you have it run in the same JAVA SDK environment so don't use the inbuilt one in Genymotion.

Then start up your device. On screen should appear some genymotion icon. Click it and you will see the IP.

Use then in the console the command "adb connect 198.123.123.123" (use your own IP of course).

After that your device list is updated.

Finally use "cordova run android" and it will install your app to the virtual device.

Same applies also for ionic framework: "ionic run android".
Caution: without any device found it will fallback to emulator...

Comment: 'On screen should appear some genymotion icon' Do you mean on screen of the virtual device screen I have no such icon just my normal looking device.

Comment: if there is no icon you can look into the settings of the virtual device and look for network

Comment: Have run cordova run android and the genymotion device - then checked the settings went into network and see just wifi ,bluetooth etc....no icon and cant understand why this would be there tbh but thanks for your help..